# Insufficient Privileges for Case Queue View

Tags: list-view

I have a User that would like to create a new list view with cases from a certain Queue.

Salesforce allows him to create the list view just fine (i.e. he can see a list of the queues) but when he tries to access the list, he receives an insufficient Privileges error.

I'm guessing the issue is that we have Accounts & Contacts (and therefore Cases) set to Private, but we're opening them up to all users if the Status = Active.  I'm also opening up all Cases to users as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the owd for cases is private, but you have a sharing rule opening access to all case records up? Is the user a member of the queue?

Comment: @Girbot He is not a member of the queue, but before we updated the Sharing Settings he could add new list views of different queues without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please click on Edit beside list view and see if the list view visibility is restricted to the Public group. If it's then it's the expected behavior.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrYbAAK

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility ...

**ListView is defined as**

- filtered on Queue = `Support`
- plus some other condition(s) like `Status = New`
- shared to members of Group `CustomerSuccess`

**OWD model is:**

- Cases: `Private`
- Cases of recordtype X shared r/w to members of role R1,R2
- Cases of recordtype Y shared r/w to members of role R2

**Queue members**

- Empty

So, a user who is a member of Group `CustomerSuccess`

- Can select the list view from dropdown - expected, listview shared to that group

Same user, a member of Role R2

- can view/edit any case via search that possesses recordtype X or Y; this too is expected because the sharing rule grants access to these cases

Same user, **without Case View All** permission

- Gets insufficient privileges on the ListView!
- This is because queue members are implicit owners so any filter on owner extends access to the records using the queue's members. But the filtered queue has no members (or at least not the running user)

So, workarounds ...

**Option 1 - Give user View All on Case**

- *(a blunt instrument and perhaps not viable in your org)*

**Option 2 - Extend queue members**

- Define as queue members the same group used to provide access to the List View

**Option 3 - Change the listview filter**

- Have `Owner = All records` and a new condition in the listview as `Case Owner = Support`.
- Inspired by [Knowledge Article: Queue Sharing Rule does not provide access to Queue List View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325673&type=1&mode=1)

---

*Aside: All this happened to me when we revoked Case View All from our Customer Support team in order to provide privileged access to subsets of cases. The main intake queue had no members (unlike in the dev/staging environments). When `Case View All` was revoked, the list views that had been working for years stopped because the underlying queue had no members - even though the users could access the cases via search or list views that didn't filter on `owner type = queue`.*

*It is much easier to start with very restrictive permissions and build up slowly with increased access then to lock down permissive access and catch every use case before deployment.*